Laravel 8.x Route Defined But still getting 404 Error
I have created many routes in web.php they are working fine but the following route is not working
$controller_prefix = "ledger_sale_returns";
$controllerClass = SaleReturnsController::class;
Route::get($controller_prefix, [$controllerClass, "index"])->name($controller_prefix . ".index");
$name ="show";
Route::get($controller_prefix . "/$name/{id}", [$controllerClass, $name])->name($controller_prefix . "." . $name);
$name = "create";
Route::get($controller_prefix . "_" . $name . "/{sale_id}", [$controllerClass, $name])->name($controller_prefix . "." . $name);

SaleReturnsController.php
class SaleReturnsController extends BackendController
{
      public function create($sale_id)
      {
      } 
 }

Bug Screenshot is below

